# Индексация страниц сайта поисковыми системами

Tags: веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста следующее: абстрактная ситуация - в файле robots.txt полностью запрещена индексация файлов \ каталогов, а в файле sitemap.xml указаны отдельные страницы. Что будет делать поисковый робот? Какой файл более приоритетный? Поясню причину возникновения вопроса, есть интернет-магазин (+ - 5000 товаров), работает на самописном движке (PHP+MySQL). Добавили функцию автогенерации карты сайта, теперь необходимо согласовать содержимое карты с файлом robots.txt.

Comment: в файл robots.txt пропишите параметром путь до sitemap.xml; `sitemap: http://example.com/site_structure/my_sitemaps1.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Файл robots.txt будет в приоритете, по крайней мере в Google, вот их [слова](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en&visit_id=1-636162690378211606-927238987&rd=1):

> While Google won't crawl or index the content blocked by robots.txt,
>   we might still find and index a disallowed URL from other places on
>   the web

Comment: Насколько я понял, Google просто может проиндексировать страницы, запрещенные для индексации на "родном" сайте, но ссылки на которые содержатся на других сайтах.

Answer (score 0):

**[Справка Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=ru)** сообщает: *Инструкции robots.txt носят рекомендательный характер*. Если вы желаете закрыть какие-то страницы от индексации, то примените **noindex** - **[info Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=ru)**. Я думаю, что для индексации важнее файл **[sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=ru)**.

Answer (score 0):

- На практике директивы из robots.txt выполняются в Google и Яндекс, поэтому страницы из закрытых каталогов не будут индексироваться.

*Смысл карты сайта состоит в указании пути для робота, определения приоритетности страницы и частоты её обновления, но никак не в запрете на индексацию.*

*Карту сайта можно сравнить со ссылками из любого меню на сайте, в котором могут быть закрыты те или иные URL.*